# browser back button on ajax innerHTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, browser-cache, innerhtml

I have an application ajax-based with call like this:

```
-----
 url='/list.php?a=1&b=2'
xmlhttp.open("GET", url,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
    document.getElementById("return").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
-------
```

If I go in another page from this and then I Clikc the BACK button of the browser, the funcion return me the initial ajax call, not saving the last ajax request that i do.
How can I display the result of last ajax call?
Tnx
Stefania

Comment: You should store the result, there are many options, localStorage, sessionStorage, cookie, ... .

Comment: You could also store it in the browser's history, if supported

Comment: I thought History.js you could not actually use because the url is not trace the call. Do you think I can use?

Comment: I resolved using session plugin of jquery and saving the call